# Is Today Between Two (DATETIME) Columns? (empty or all zeroes count as unbound upper/lower limit)

Tags: mysql

I have a table of products and two DATETIME columns, one for start_date and one for end_date.

How do I check if a specific product ID is between the start date and end date? However, if one or both of these is NULL (the default value) accept this lower/upper bound to be unlimited and return the product if it's still within the other bound (if it's set). If both bounds are set to NULL always return the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from your_table
where
product_id = 1 AND
(
   (CURDATE() between start_date and end_date) 
   or (CURDATE() >= start_date and end_date is null) 
   or (CURDATE() <= end_date and start_date is null)
   or (start_date is null and end_date is null)
)
```

Comment: +1. Though you may need one more condition to handle when they are both null.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when ('2012-06-26' between start_date and end_date) 
                or ('2012-06-26' >= start_date and end_date is null) 
                or ('2012-06-26' <= end_date and start_date is null)
            then 1
            else 0
            end as is_between_dates
from your_table
where product_id = 1
```